# JQuery Mobile: Page navigation doesn't always work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery Mobile and MVC4.

**MARKUP:**

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="d" id="main">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Test Page</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <h2>Test Page</h2>

        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Navigation</li>
            <li><a href="#Page1">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Page2">Page 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

@Html.Partial("Page1")

@Html.Partial("Page2")
```

Let's say this is at `localhost\subpage`.
When I navigate directly to `localhost\subpage`, then all is well and I can navigate between pages. However, if I go to this page from another page via a link, then the navigation no longer works.. I cannot navigate to `#page1` or `#page2` anymore.. and when I use Firebug, I can see the pages are not even in the DOM... whereas in the first scenario (direct URL), I can see they are there but hidden, as they should be.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

Page content as requested:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="d" id="Page1" data-url="Page1">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
    <p>This is page 1</p>
</div>
```

Page 2 is basically the same as the above.

Comment: OK, you can try this: @Html.Partial("~/Page1") and @Html.Partial("~/Page2"), but I don't know will it help. Try it and post what happens

Comment: That doesn't help, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you post code for link that you call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add `data-ajax="false"` to the anchor tag. Working fine now...